# How can I remove Orphan Packages in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, yum, dnf

I just switched from Ubuntu to Fedora14. In Ubuntu we had the `apt-get autoremove` thing to remove orphan/unused packages.  What is the counterpart in Fedora?

Answer (score 41):

DNF, the yum replacement since Fedora 22, also provides a `autoremove` subcommand which is [modeled after](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=963345) apt-get/yum autoremove.

Examples:

```
# dnf autoremove
```

which tries to remove all automatically installed and otherwise unused dependency packages - should be pretty much equivalent to `apt-get autoremove`.

```
# dnf autoremove examplepackage
```

which removes examplepackage and all its automatically installed (and otherwise unused) dependencies.

### Yum

Yum has the autoremove command since Fedora 19, and it is documented since Fedora 20/RHEL 7.

The usage is analogous to the dnf implementation, e.g.:

```
# yum autoremove
```

or

```
# yum autoremove examplepackage
```

### Change the behavior of yum removes

Yum supports a config option to change the default behavior of the `remove` subcommand (e.g. via /etc/yum.conf):

```
clean_requirements_on_remove=yes
```

[yum.conf(5)](http://grisha.biz/cgi-bin/man?query=yum.conf&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=CentOS+release+5.3+%28Final%29)

When this is set, the next `yum remove` also tries to remove auto installed dependencies iff they are not needed by other packages.

You can also temporarily test this option via something like:

```
# yum --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1 remove examplepackage
```

### Workaround for old Fedora version

(For Fedora versions where the yum autoremove subcommand is not available and/or `clean_requirements_on_remove` does not work.)

Although during installation of packages installed dependencies are marked as such (seems to be relatively new feature of rpm/yum).

You can find unneeded dependencies via:

```
$ package-cleanup --leaves -q --all \
    | xargs repoquery --installed --qf '%{nvra} - %{yumdb_info.reason}' \
    | grep -- '- dep' \
    | cut -d' ' -f1 > tmp
```

This command line is inspired by [fenris02's script](http://fedorapeople.org/cgit/fenris02/public_git/cleanup.git/plain/show-leaves.sh).

After inspection of `tmp` (and perhaps curation) you could remove them via something like this:

```
# xargs yum remove < tmp
```

Comment: It gave the error "Invalid yumdb querytag 'reason' for installed pkg: adobe-release-x86_64-1.0-1.noarch". What is this now?

Comment: @c0da, I guess that the feature that yum records in its database the 'reason' of installation (e.g.'dep' or 'user') for each package is relatively new. Perhaps your Fedora instance predates the introduction of that feature such that you have still (a few) old packages installed without that tag set.

Comment: I installed Fedora 18 a few days back. So I think the required tag should be there.

Comment: @c0da, perhaps the 'reason' was not recorded because you have installed the package `adobe-release` via [`yum localinstall`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82880/how-to-replicate-installed-package-selection-from-one-fedora-instance-to-another#comment122828_82882)

Answer (score 38):

`package-cleanup --quiet --leaves` from the *yum-utils* package will list the library packages which aren't relied upon by other packages. Unfortunately it tends to be a bit overeager. On my system, for example, it suggested removing libvirt. Adding the `--exclude-bin` argument helps. If you're happy with it's suggestion, then to clean up the packages, do:

```
# package-cleanup --quiet --leaves --exclude-bin | xargs yum remove -y
```

Comment: Tested it after installing and removing `netbeans-platform` and package-cleanup lists some stuff but actually none of the previously installed `netbeans-platform` dependencies (using Fedora 17).

Comment: Doesn't work, as pointed by @maxschlepzig

Answer (score 16):

you need to install the yum plugin "remove-with-leaves":

```
# yum install yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves.noarch
```

once installed:

```
# yum remove --remove-leaves package
```

good luck!

Comment: and how to run it for all installed apps?

Comment: Does not seem to be very reliable as well: http://skvidal.wordpress.com/2010/11/09/orphaned-dep-cleanup-in-yum/

Comment: RHEL/CentOS/Oracle Linux 6 needs the `yum-plugin-remove-with-leaves.noarch` package installed to use `package-cleanup`

Answer (score 8):

```
# package-cleanup --orphans >/tmp/junk
```

edit the `/tmp/junk` file and remove the first line which is informational
from the command line enter the following:

```
for file in `cat /tmp/junk`
do
  yum remove $file
done
```

Comment: package-cleanup(1) says: '--orphans List  installed  packages which are not available from currently configured repositories.' This is not equivalent to what `apt-get autoremove` does. apt-get(8) says: 'autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for some package and that are no more needed.'

Comment: Doesn't work! I must have been mistaken previously. Thanks @maxschlepzig

Comment: This used to work for me but in CentOS 6.6 it actually lists all installed packages, not just orphans.

Answer (score 4):

***NOTE:*** This answer is correct but only applies to RHEL 7+ and Fedora 20+ (where autoremove has been added as a new feature).

```
# yum autoremove
```

Just confirm to remove the selected packages.

Answer (score 2):

With `dnf` you can now use for orphans (packages that are not in repositories):

```
dnf repoquery --extras
```

and for leaves (unused libraries):

```
dnf repoquery --unneeded
```

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Larry Mohr's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23331/20030):

```
package-cleanup --orphans | sed '1d' | sed '/^ * /d' | sed '/Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile/d' | xargs sudo yum remove
```

(Includes skipping for fastest mirror, if you wonder.)

Answer (score 0):

**In Fedora, the orphan package means no candidate repos for it to update!**

1. If the orphan packages were generated by you disable yum.repos.d/some.conf.

   ```
   yum distro-sync
   ```
2. Other orphan packages, the command may be dangerous.

   ```
   yum remove $(package-cleanup --orphans)
   ```

   or, just use the safety command.

   ```
   yum remove name-of-page
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to not cause these issues is to to use transactions.

After setup base system, as you install using yum, it creates transactions. When you intend to remove things, rollback the transactions.

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/24/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-DNF-Transaction_History.html

Answer (score 0):

```
yum -y remove $(package-cleanup --orphans | sed -n '/*/,//p' | grep -v \*)
```