# How to make unused dependencies clean with yum?

Tags: fedora, centos, rhel, yum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I remove Orphan Packages in Fedora?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23330/how-can-i-remove-orphan-packages-in-fedora)

I need something equal gentoo's

```
emerge --depclean
```

so how to make unused dependencies clean with yum?