# Remove unused packages

Tags: yum, rpm

I have installed some rpm package on my Fedora 17. Some packages had a lot of dependencies.
I have removed some packages but I forgot remove unused dependencies with yum remove.

How can I do that now?

Comment: Have you looked at the `yum` manpage: http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum ?

Comment: duplicate of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23330/how-can-i-remove-orphan-packages-in-fedora

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's not easy.  How do you differentiate between "a file that was required by something I have since removed" from "a file that is not required by anything else that I really want"?

You can use the `package-cleanup` command from the `yum-utils` package to list "leaf nodes" in your package dependency graph.  These are packages that can be removed without affecting anything else:

```
$ package-cleanup --leaves
```

This will produce a list of "libraries" on which nothing else depends.  In most cases you can safely remove these packages.  If you add `--all` to the command line:

```
$ package-cleanup --leaves --all
```

You'll get packages that aren't considered libraries, also, but this list is going to be so long that it probably won't be useful.

Comment: APT (the Debian equivalent of Yum) has a notion of “automatically installed package”. If a package wasn't explicitly requested but only pulled in as a dependency, it'll be automatically removed (with a confirmation prompt) if the packages that depend on it are all removed. Without an indication of this type, it is indeed not easy.

Comment: missed command to remove all packages directly from `package-cleanup --leaves`

Answer (score 132):

If you install a package with `yum install`, say `pdftk`, it will pull in a lot of dependencies:

```
Installed:
  pdftk.x86_64 0:1.44-10.fc18

Dependency Installed:
  bouncycastle.noarch 0:1.46-6.fc18     
  itext-core.noarch 0:2.1.7-14.fc18     
  libgcj.x86_64 0:4.7.2-8.fc18          
  bouncycastle-mail.noarch 0:1.46-6.fc18
  java-1.5.0-gcj.x86_64 0:1.5.0.0-40.fc18
  sinjdoc.x86_64 0:0.5-13.fc18
  bouncycastle-tsp.noarch 0:1.46-5.fc18
  java_cup.noarch 1:0.11a-10.fc18
  itext.x86_64 0:2.1.7-14.fc18   
  javamail.noarch 0:1.4.3-12.fc18

Complete!
```

`yum remove pdftk` will remove only that package and not all the dependencies.

But you can look at all the 'transactions' (install, remove etc.):

```
$ sudo yum history list pdftk
ID     | Command line             | Date and time    | Action(s)      | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
    88 | install pdftk            | 2012-12-14 13:35 | Install        |   11
```

And then you can undo that transaction:

```
$ sudo yum history undo 88
Undoing transaction 88, from Fri Dec 14 13:35:34 2012
    Dep-Install bouncycastle-1.46-6.fc18.noarch       @fedora
    Dep-Install bouncycastle-mail-1.46-6.fc18.noarch  @fedora
    Dep-Install bouncycastle-tsp-1.46-5.fc18.noarch   @fedora
    Dep-Install itext-2.1.7-14.fc18.x86_64            @fedora
    Dep-Install itext-core-2.1.7-14.fc18.noarch       @fedora
    Dep-Install java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0-40.fc18.x86_64 @fedora
    Dep-Install java_cup-1:0.11a-10.fc18.noarch       @fedora
    Dep-Install javamail-1.4.3-12.fc18.noarch         @fedora
    Dep-Install libgcj-4.7.2-8.fc18.x86_64            @fedora
    Install     pdftk-1.44-10.fc18.x86_64             @fedora
    Dep-Install sinjdoc-0.5-13.fc18.x86_64            @fedora
    ...
    Complete!
```

Comment: +1 Awesome solution and very easy to do. I've never heard of `yum history`. Thanks!

Comment: And what if 89 depends on java_cup or libgcj?

Comment: Shouldn't this be an accepted answer?

Comment: @WernerCD, in debian dpkg etc comlains that a package can not be removed if another depends on it. Ohe could hope the same happens here.

Comment: No longer necessary, see some of the other answers...

Answer (score 97):

Starting from Fedora 18, you can simply use this command

```
yum autoremove
```

or

```
yum remove --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1
```

You can also apply autoremove command with specific package

```
yum autoremove <package>
```

Which will remove unneeded dependencies from that installed package. `autoremove` is very much an alias of `remove --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1` but for some reasons, is still undocumented.

Comment: command `yum remove --setopt=clean_requirements_on_remove=1` works for me in centOS

Comment: For me the `package-cleanup --leaves && yum autoremove` removed libvorbis and so made the internet-radio-streaming "Ices" application die -- probably because it isn't in repos and I had to compile it.

Comment: Command `yum autoremove` works on CentOS 7.6 as well.

Comment: yum autoremove fails to remove 4 old kernels on CentOS 7

Answer (score 12):

I took larsks answer one step farther.

```
$ package-cleanup -q --leaves | xargs -l1 yum -y remove
```

This grabs all of the dependencies that can be removed without affecting anything else and then removes them. Better then going through one by one.

"-q" is useful on some systems which print "Setting up yum" otherwise, causing this command to remove yum. And that's not what you want.

Comment: `package-cleanup` outputs "Setting up yum" on my machine, which resulted in Yum removing itself. I'm now trying to figure out how to sort this out.

Comment: @PaulLammertsma just add `-q` option to package-cleanup. This happened to me as well :D

Comment: `package-cleanup -q --leaves | xargs -r -l1 yum -y remove` will silently skip xargs if package-cleanup output is empty, useful for automated scripts like ansible, chef, puppet, vagrant

Comment: this is The Answer.

Comment: Because "...removed without affecting anything else..." you should remove the `-y` so that future users won't get burned by whatever burned @Paul Lammertsma

Answer (score 6):

In newer Fedoras with `dnf`, you can use `dnf  repoquery --unneeded` as a replacement for `package-cleanup --leaves`.