# How to yum list installed packages that are not in repositories

Tags: rhel, yum, oracle-linux

I'm running Oracle Linux/RHEL and trying to get a list of installed packages whose name/arch is not in any active repository. When doing `yum list installed` these packages are displayed in red, but is there any yum command to only list those?

Answer (score 0):

This is **strictly** for OL7:

```bsh
sudo yum list installed | egrep -v "@ol7|@anaconda"
```

You can see all your repos by:

```bsh
sudo yum list installed | grep -v "Loaded plugins" | awk '{print $3}' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible to easily answer your question for any "*active* repository", but we can find all packages not installed via a repository with:

```
awk 'NR <=3 { next; } { while (NF < 3) 
  { getline more; $0=$0 more; } }  
  $3 !~ /^@/ {  print }' \
 <( yum list installed )
```

If you are interested in packages which are not among the currently *enabled* repositories, but may have been installed by ones which are active or no longer known to the system, you can do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && FNR > 1 { sub(/^!/,"",$1); repos["@" $1]=1; next; } 
  FNR <=3 { next; } { while (NF < 3) { getline more; $0=$0 more; } } 
  !($3 in repos) {  print }' \
<( yum repolist enabled ; echo anaconda ) \
<( yum list installed )
```

For awk n00bs, the `FNR==NR` is an idiom to separate the first input file/stream from the rest of the inputs. That part loads the repository names into a hash, with the following caveats:

- Those repo names beginning with `!` are included, and the `!` is excluded.
- The `@` is prepended to the name for faster look-up when comparing against the final field in the installed-list.

Now, the complex-looking middle program simply recombines lines that yum automatically splits. As long as the input line has fewer than 3 columns/fields, append the next line to it.

The last program either tests if the third field begins with an @ or if it is in the list of repos.

Note: `yum repolist enabled ; echo anaconda`  appends "anaconda" to the repolist so that the  packages installed at os-install time are also excluded.

Comment: This is what `package-cleanup --orphans` does: `List installed packages which are not available from currently configured repositories.` See this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/190114

Comment: OK, well the question was regarding `yum`. The question you linked to is related purely for a particular Fedora distribution, but this one here is more general.  None of my systems have `package-cleanup` installed by default.